# used sharing URL Encoding function in asp and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, url-encoding

I want to use url decode and encode in asp and asp.net. I already have to use an application that is session bridge in asp.net and asp. Now, I want to use url encoding function shared. How could I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding function that supports unicode and works in both asp and asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491550/encoding-function-that-supports-unicode-and-works-in-both-asp-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to write url encoding/decoding function in .NET and then share it as COM component so that ASP code can use it.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not enough. So, I asked a full post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490247/how-to-use-url-encoding-function-between-asp-net-and-asp. Please help me. Thank for reply.