# How to use url encoding function between asp.net and asp

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, url-encoding

I want to write the two functions that is used for asp.net and asp. I want to write two version. This function is used url encode and decode. Now, I got a new problem. This is how to work server.urlencode. So, how to implement this url encode function. I have url decode function for asp. I try to get url encode function for asp. So that, I can write url encode and decode in asp.net. Please, help me.

This is url decode function.

```
Function URLDecode(sConvert)
    Dim aSplit
    Dim sOutput
    Dim I
    If IsNull(sConvert) Then
       URLDecode = ""
       Exit Function
    End If

    ' convert all pluses to spaces
    sOutput = REPLACE(sConvert, "+", " ")

    ' next convert %hexdigits to the character
    aSplit = Split(sOutput, "%")

    If IsArray(aSplit) Then
      sOutput = aSplit(0)
      For I = 0 to UBound(aSplit) - 1
        sOutput = sOutput & _
          Chr("&H" & Left(aSplit(i + 1), 2)) &_
          Right(aSplit(i + 1), Len(aSplit(i + 1)) - 2)
      Next
    End If

    URLDecode = sOutput
End Function
```

I got [this](http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp#urldecode).

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET with your ASP.NET pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding function that supports unicode and works in both asp and asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491550/encoding-function-that-supports-unicode-and-works-in-both-asp-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is a hog when it comes to string parsing so here is the same decode done in JScript:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
// This function decodes the any string
// that's been encoded using URL encoding technique
function URLDecode(psEncodeString) 
{
  return unescape(psEncodeString); 
}
</script>
```

http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl006_url.asp

.NET has HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode and HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode functions built in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx